# Argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable raspberry pi

Tags: python

Im writing voice control code that is as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time
import aiy.audio
import aiy.cloudspeech
import aiy.voicehat
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
def main():
    recognizer = aiy.cloudspeech.get_recognizer()
    recognizer.expect_phrase('OK Google"')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('turn off the light')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('turn on the light')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('blink')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('repeat after me')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('new light')
    button = aiy.voicehat.get_button()
    led = aiy.voicehat.get_led()
    aiy.audio.get_recorder().start()

    while True:
        text = recognizer.recognize()
        while 'OK Google' not in text:
            text = recognizer.recognize()
        text  = text.replace('OK Google ', '', 1)
        if text is None:
            print('Sorry, I did not hear you.')
        else:
            print('You said "', text, '"')
            if 'turn on the light' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.ON)
            elif 'turn off the light' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.OFF)
            elif 'blink' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.BLINK)
            elif 'repeat after me' in text:
                to_repeat = text.replace('repeat after me', '', 1)
                aiy.audio.say(to_repeat)
            elif 'new light' in text:
                GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(.75)
                GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
            elif 'goodbye' in text:
                os._exit(0)
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.OFF)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is for python on Raspberry pi, and it is supposed to listen for OK Google then return the text and maybe do an action. Normally, it works fine;However if I don't say anything for a while it gives me an error, saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copyspeech.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "copyspeech.py", line 31, in main
    while 'OK Google' not in text:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Anyone know why?
I'm fairly new at python.

Comment: Is this particular enough for your Raspberry Pi to mention it in the title?

Comment: I can't find proper documentation for that module, but from looking at the source code... it just returns `None` sometimes. Add a `text is not None` check and you're done.